# Possible to have a WebAPI method exposed (Get or Post) that can be called like an Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

That's probably not horribly clear so let me elaborate:

As I currently know, the "action" of the web api controller is determined by the number and types of parameters. So if you pass in two strings, you'll get the Get or Post that has two strings in the method signature.

What I'd like to do is set up several routes like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "fileFunctionsDelete",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{appName}/{userID}/Delete",
    defaults: new {
        appName = RouteParameter.Optional,
        userID= RouteParameter.Optional,
        fileAction= RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "fileFunctionsUpload",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{appName}/{userID}/Upload",
    defaults: new {
        appName = RouteParameter.Optional,
        userID= RouteParameter.Optional,
        fileAction= RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

These should obviously go to the same controller but in an MVC website, I'd go to an action named "Delete" or "Upload".

So far, all I see are Gets and Posts with the number and type of params being used to determine what is called. That's just too confusing.

Is there any way to make it more "MVC website"-like in call behavior?

---

> To clarify: If I want a specific action to fire, I call it by name. "public ActionResult ThisAction(object[] params). In the web api, all the sigatures are like Get or Put or Post. I want to be able to say something like "url:../Delete" and it calls the appropriate delete get or post. I don't want to have to differentiate my methods by the number of parameters I pass in or parse a string to see what the user intended. Those are recipes for failure

**UPDATE:**

The answers by Kenneth, lgor, and Tu Hoang all have critical information that needs to be taken together (constraining the method for the route, action, model properties, etc) and each have information that makes a complete answer. I can't mark them all so I'm marking the "most correct" for my question.

Comment: I don't understand your question, MVC controllers and WebAPI controllers are for the most part the same thing, in fact in ASP.NET MVC Core they have combined everything.  What is causing you confusion?

Comment: If I want a specific action to fire, I call it by name. "public ActionResult ThisAction(object[] params). In the web api, all the sigatures are like Get or Put or Post. I want to be able to say something like "url:../Delete" and it calls the appropriate delete get or post. I don't want to have to differentiate my methods by the number of parameters I pass in or parse a string to see what the user intended. Those are recipes for failure.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, are you trying to understand how to use the HTTP Verbs on your controller along with how to use the `Html.ActionLink` along with those verbs?

Comment: Have you looked at [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) yet? It's a bit more focused to apply than modifying route config, IMO.

Comment: Does attribute routing work with web api? because if it does, then post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Did you note the title of the linked article?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: If you look at the sample routes I provided, it should be really clear what I'm trying to do. I want to call those routes to determine the method I want to fire instead of hoping that 2 or more methods in a file api aren't going to need the same number and types of parameters.

Comment: @KennethK.I feel silly. Dang. Please post that as an answer and we're golden.

Comment: Alternatively (to the proposed answer by Kennith) you can use `{action}` in your route template as a placeholder just like you can `{controller}`. This would allow routing to work just like it does in MVC routing. Example from your first route template string: `api/{controller}/{appName}/{userID}/{action}`

Comment: Whoa, that's game changing. I might look into that if it's simpler to implement. Pop as answer with a sample method signature? This would be far cleaner if I'm reading you right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I find attribute routing to be a bit easier to work with when you want custom routes on your actions. [As exemplified](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) on the official ASP.NET website, you can apply routes directly to your actions using the `[Route]` attribute:

e.g.

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Customer/{model.LastName}/{model.FirstName}/Upload")]
    public void Post(CustomerModel model)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

I can't recall if you can substitute in `{controller}` the way you can in the default routes, but I believe you can. I've got a complex object coming in as the parameter, hence the dot notation, but if you're just using simply types, then you can use the variable names directly (e.g. `[Route("api/Customer/{lastName}/{firstName}/Upload")]`).

There's also the `[RoutePrefix]` attribute which you can apply to the controller so that you don't have to repeat `api/Customer/`, for example, on every action:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{model.LastName}/{model.FirstName}/Upload")]
    public void Post(CustomerModel model)
```

This isn't a terribly good example since I'm demonstrating a POST and the parameters are coming via the URL, but it should demonstrate the idea.

Comment: This combined with the link you provided is absolutely incredible. There's a few other things in the other answers that I'll implement but, wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `action` placeholder in the `routeTemplate` the same as you do in MVC. See the code below, I replaced `Delete` with `{action}`. It might get tricky though if you in between parameters are optional so order might be critical here, I would prefer if it was `api/{controller}/{action}/{appName}/{userID}/` or `api/{action}/{controller}/{appName}/{userID}/`.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "fileFunctionsDelete",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{appName}/{userID}/{action}",
    defaults: new {
        appName = RouteParameter.Optional,
        userID= RouteParameter.Optional,
        fileAction= RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

> (from comment) ... with a sample method signature

The method signature would be as any other signature.

```
// I am not sure what type of parameters these are so I am going to take a wild guess
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string appName = null, int? userID = null, CancellationToken token) {}
```

It just depends on what you are passing it. This works fine, the same, with post, put, get, delete, or custom names that you might have. Just remember to apply the HttpGet/HttpPost/HttpPut/HttpDelete attributes if you want to limit access based on the http verb (nothing different here).

---

You can also use the Route and RoutePrefix attributes as specified by Kennith. I will not steal his answer, it is a good one and also perfectly acceptable if not preferred depending on the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the param ordering. I'm going to implement that. Excellent advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like below? You need `action` defaults and matching `ActionName` attribute on the controller action.

That being said, your route samples look like it will need some work. Specifically, what does it mean to have all route parameters optional. What does delete do if `userId` is optional? Will route even be valid if `appName` is optional.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "fileFunctionsDelete",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{appName}/{userID}/Delete",
    defaults: new {
        appName = RouteParameter.Optional,
        userID= RouteParameter.Optional,
        action = "Delete"
    },
    constraints: new { HttpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
);

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Delete")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteUser(
    string controller,
    string appName,
    string userID)
{
}
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution that I have been looking for. One thing: {Controller} is not specified in the param list in the route and therefore matches against any controller that has the "right name". I'll try this one and if it doesn't work, I'll let you know.

Comment: Ultimately, I didn't like this because it doesn't scale with the 30 or so methods I need to implement (not by my choice)  but the constraints in your route is pure magic. That's definitely going in. Thanks.